# Is the retirement community in Homecoming, really a retirement community?

Tags: plot-explanation, homecoming

In the third episode of the conspiracy-heavy TV series, *Homecoming*, recovering veteran Joseph Shrier convinces his former comrade Walter Cruz that they need to escape Mirror Pond's wellness center/Homecoming program, believing that something nefarious is happening. Shrier wants to prove to Walter that they may not even be in Florida, like they have been told.

[image: village]

The two then steal a van and take a little [thematic] road trip. It takes them a long time, *travelling from day to night*, before they come across a small village, which results in Shrier almost killing a man, mistaking a flashlight hanging from his belt as an offensive weapon. Later, after going back to the wellness center, they are told that this is retirement community.

**But is this really a retirement community?**

Things to consider:

1. Geist (Mirror Pond/Homecoming) is a military contractor doing something nefarious to veterans.
2. The Village seems like a throw back to an earlier time period and reminds me of other military exercises (like Russian Sleeper Agents role-play scenarios). While driving, Shrier points out that the military has done stuff like this before. (build replicas)
3. The Wellness Center plays up the idea of rehabilitation by making the recovering vets role-play common workplace scenarios like "Shoe Store Job Interview"
4. The village scene only showed viewers one man, we never see any other people.
5. Joseph Shrier is *kicked out* of the program right after this incident.
6. The Mirror Pond facility is later recontextualized to incorporate a "mall-like" scenario. (aka "store front")

Comment: How is this primarily opinion based? Even though the season one story is mostly self contained and we don't have a greenlight for a second season yet, there was a lot of hints that this was really a granular in a bigger Giest sandbox and so a second season could easily happen. in addition there could be interviews coming out that may address this loose subplot thread.

Answer (score 1):

It could be either since it's not shown again, I guess we will have to wait for a second season (if they address that). After Walter discussed the event in a session I just assumed it was a retirement community.

The reason why Shrier got kicked out was his increased paranoia - Colin actually wanted to expel both Shrier and Walter because it was not the type of result he was looking for in the "clients". So far there's no more evidence in the show - it doesn't seem to be important for the overall plot.

Comment: Ya, I just wasn't sure if the EPs would bring it up/talk about it in an interview or not, because sometimes they do mention additional stuff after the fact, but I do feel like given how BIG Geist is, that this *could be subplot for a later season. I just saw no evidence that it was a retirement community either, but 1+ because it seems there is no information as it currently stands! :)